# Hibernate error when creating session to database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Even using annotations or XML for mapping I face the same error, debugging I noticed that this line

`factory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();`

never get executed, my print is show in the hibernate log:

Here is the hibernate log:

> Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final} Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000205: Loaded
>   properties from resource hibernate.properties:
>   {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver,
>   hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5,
>   hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect,
>   hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true,
>   hibernate.connection.username=sa,
>   hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000,
>   hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false,
>   hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
>   Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM
>   org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialService  INFO:
>   HHH80000001: hibernate-spatial integration enabled : true Criou
>   arquivo de configuração XML! Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>   at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aps] Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=victor,
>   password=****} Dec 02, 2017 1:14:55 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false Dec 02, 2017
>   1:14:56 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 5 (min=1) Dec
>   02, 2017 1:14:56 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO:
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
>   **Falha ao criar sessão** 
>   Dec 02, 2017 1:14:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   stop INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool
>   [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aps]

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aps</property>
    <property name="connection.username">victor</property>
    <property name="connection.password">123456</property>

    <property name ="dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    </property>

    <mapping class="br.unip.beans.Atividade"/>
    <mapping class="br.unip.beans.Projeto"/>
    <mapping class="br.unip.beans.Usuario"/>
    <mapping class="br.unip.beans.Projeto_has_usuario"/>

</session-factory>
```

Function where it happens

```
private static SessionFactory factory; 

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            factory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Falha ao criar sessão");

            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
    }
```

[image of the package explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI9E9.png)

Comment: Print the stack trace of the exception instead of just ignoring it, and you'll know what the problem is, and thus will be able to fix it. Hiding the error is the best way to not know what it is.

Comment: System.out.println("Falha ao criar sessão");  -> don't eat the exception, print it out and you'll get more details

Comment: Which hibernate version are you using? Also previous users are correct - print stacktrace for more info.

Comment: Oh sorry, fixed looking into the stack trace :) Thanks!